# Horizontal Centering TextView in RelativeLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't place my textview in RelativeLayout in the center. I added this parameters

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

but it doesn't help.

**My Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ru.myseolife.a99torrentsalpha2.MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nothing_found"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/nothingfound"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anybody know what can it be? TextView is centering vertically, but horizontally it appears in the left side.

Comment: add  android:gravity="center" to your textview.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb thanks, it helped, but i thought that android:gravity="center" works for child elements.

Comment: In the case of the textview it will be applied to the text, did it work or not?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Yes, it works

Comment: Ok, then let me share it as an answer maybe other will find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TextView` `layout_width` is `match_parent` If you want to keep that and show it as centered you need to center the text inside the view not the `TextView`

So use  `android:gravity="center"` inside your `TextView` or you can make `TextView`'s width `wrap_content` and keep the way as it is.

Since it's a simple answer i'll tell you a trick > go to
settings > developer options > and tick **Show layout boundaries** then you can check the view bounds and get the idea where actually your view boundaries are !

Comment: great job, well explained.

Comment: @Abdenaceur Lichiheb Well why should i copy paste someones comment being 0.13% in this quarter? you are not the only one who knows android mister !!

Answer (score 0):

the width of TextView should be "wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to your textview, this will center the text since you are setting the width as match parent.